# Lazy evaluation of Optional

Tags: java, lazy-evaluation, option-type

Is it possibile to have an `java.util.Optional` which is evaluated only if needed?

I need to pass an `Optional` to a method (of an API that I cannot change), and this method may or may not make use the value of that `Optional`. Since the value is computed by a heavy operation, I'd like to compute that value only when (and if) it is needed, e.g. calling `get()`, `orElseGet()`, `ifPresent()`, etc.

Something like `Optional.ofLazy(Supplier<T> computeValue)`.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about `java.util.Optional` (not Guava) - `Optional` is `final`, and doesn't already expose such behaviour.  So there's no way to achieve this without modifying your API.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Your comment headed me to the right direction: inspecting the source code of `java.util.Optional` it's pretty clear this behavior is not supported in Java 8 nor 9 (yet).

Comment: @GiovanniLovato - Oh!  I just looked at the Javadoc :)

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a `Supplier` which returns an `Optional`. `Supplier` makes the lazy part.

Conceptual code:

```
Foo heavyComputation() { ... }

void main() {
    Supplier<Optional<Foo>> sup = () -> heavyComputation();
    doSomethingWhichMayNeedHeavyResult(sup);
}

void doSomethingWhichMayNeedHeavyResult(Supplier<Optional<Foo>> sup) {
    if (electricityIsTooCheap) {
       Foo foo = sup.get().get().orElse(null); // This will lazy load.
    }
}
```

For brevity, I would also like to have something which combines both into one, but that will come later I guess.

Comment: +1. It may also be wise to decorate the `Supplier` with some logic to cache and reuse the result if its `get` method is invoked multiple times.

Comment: May be worth mentioning that probably in most use cases, due to the lazy evaluation, Supplier<Foo> will suffice.  If you need a Foo then you're unlikely to be able to proceed without one ...

Answer (score -1):

In the name of brevity, I think `orElseGet` is what you're after:

```
void foo() {
    System.out.println("Prints only foo");
    System.out.println(Optional.of("foo").orElseGet(() -> other()));
    System.out.println("Prints foo and bar");
    System.out.println(Optional.of("foo").orElse(other()));
}
private String other() {
    System.out.println("bar");
    return "bar";
}
```